# WebCryptoApi: Cannot wrap&unwrap aes-gcm key into&from "jwk" format with "encrypt" and "decrypt" active

Tags: webcrypto-api, jwk

I'm generating a key for encrypting data, then wrap it using a master key and store it alongside the encrypted data. All is well when wrapping into `raw` format, but when wrapping as `jwk` I get the error `DOMException: Data provided to an operation does not meet requirements`.

It works when specifying they key for being used either for encryption or for decryption, but not when both are specified as key usages.

```
let wrapAlgo = {
    name: "AES-KW",
    length: 256
};
let encAlgo = {
    name:"AES-GCM",
    length:256
}
let format = "jwk";
let extractable=true;
let keyUsages = ["encrypt", "decrypt"];

let kek = await crypto.subtle.generateKey(
    wrapAlgo, 
    false, 
    ["wrapKey", "unwrapKey"]
);

let key = await window.crypto.subtle.generateKey(
    encAlgo,
    extractable, // the key is extractable (i.e. can be used in exportKey)
    keyUsages
);
console.log("key", key);

let wrappedKey = await crypto.subtle.wrapKey(
    format,
    key,
    kek,
    wrapAlgo
);
console.log("wrappedKey", wrappedKey);

let unwrappedKey = await crypto.subtle.unwrapKey(
    format,
    wrappedKey,
    kek,
    wrapAlgo,
    encAlgo,
    extractable,
    keyUsages
);
console.log("key", await crypto.subtle.exportKey("jwk", unwrappedKey));
```

Comment: jwk as format is not supported for AES-KW. This is plausible since the format specifies in which format the key is exported before it is encrypted. AES-KW expects a multiple of 8 bytes, which is satisfied for raw AES keys, but generally not for AES keys with jwk as format. jwk as format is however possible for other wrapping algorithms (e.g. AES-GCM).

Comment: This would make sense if it wouldn't work for the keyUsages "encrypt" or "decrypt" either. When you modify the code above by setting `keyUsages` to `["encrypt"]` it works just fine, same with `["decrypt"]`

Comment: Your reasoning _if it works for case x or y, then it must work in general_ is illogical. Your own example shows that the jwk format does not work for AES-KW _in general_. Another example is the [AES-KW example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubtleCrypto/wrapKey#raw_wrap) from the webcrypto documentation. If you replace `raw` with `jwk` in the `wrapKey` call, it doesn't work anymore. Another hint [here](https://github.com/diafygi/webcrypto-examples#aes-kw---wrapkey). But I like to be taught better. I'm curious if it's _generally_ possible to combine jwk and AES-KW.

Comment: Ok, I see what you mean and thank you for your explanation. When going to bed yesterday after posting my comment I thought "but what if the length of the `jwk`-export changes depending on what operations the key supports", which would reveal the ignorance of my last comment. I just looked at the export of the `jwk`with different `keyUsages` which confirmed my suspicion, I just didn't know that the `keyUsages` are actually stored in the jwk. So yeah, your first comment is the correct answer to the question. Do you want to post it as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: I was about to post a similar example that outputs the length of the key exported and serialized as JWK. In the cases with `keyUsages` `["encrypt"]` or `["decrypt"]` this is 112 bytes (112%8=0), in the case `["encrypt", "decrypt"]` 122 bytes (122%8=2), so because of the AES-KW condition of a multiple of 8 bytes, the former is compatible with AES-KW and the latter is not, which explains the behavior. I'll try to write an answer to this later today.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AES-KW is a key wrap algorithm described in [RFC3394](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3394). The algorithm is used to wrap i. e. encrypt a key. The input, i.e. the key to be encrypted, must be an integer multiple of 8 bytes, s. also [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubtleCrypto/wrapKey#aes-kw).

The key to be encrypted is passed in [`SubtleCrypto.wrapKey()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubtleCrypto/wrapKey) in the 2nd parameter `key` as [`CryptoKey`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CryptoKey) and must therefore be exported before the actual encryption. For this purpose the format in which the key is exported is specified in the 1st parameter `format`:

```js
const result = crypto.subtle.wrapKey(format, key, wrappingKey, wrapAlgo);
```

In the posted example, the key to be wrapped is a 32 bytes key for AES-256. In `raw` format, the key thus satisfies the AES-KW length criterion. In `jwk` format, however, the length criterion is generally not met:
If the key exported in `jwk` format is serialized, it has a length for the key usage `["encrypt"]` or `["decrypt"]` that happens to be an integer multiple of 8 bytes (112 bytes), while this is not the case for the key usages `["encrypt", "decrypt"]` (122 bytes):

```js
(async () => {
    async function getLength(keyUsages) {  
        var key = await window.crypto.subtle.generateKey(
            {name:"AES-GCM", length: 256},
            true, 
            keyUsages
        );
        var expkey = await crypto.subtle.exportKey("jwk", key)
        var expkeySerLen = JSON.stringify(expkey).length;
        return {KeyUsages: keyUsages, length: expkeySerLen, lenMod8: expkeySerLen % 8}; 
    }
    console.log(await getLength(["encrypt"]));            // works
    console.log(await getLength(["decrypt"]));            // works
    console.log(await getLength(["encrypt", "decrypt"])); // doesn't work
})();
```

This is most likely the reason why the code with the key usage `["encrypt"]` or `["decrypt"]` is executed, but not the code for the key usages `["encrypt", "decrypt"]`.

The bottom line is that AES-KW works *reliably* for the `raw` format, but not for the `jwk` format.

However, the `jwk` format can be used in `SubtleCrypto.wrapKey()` for other wrapping algorithms, such as AES-GCM:

```js
(async () => {

    let encAlgo = {
        name:"AES-GCM",
        length:256
    };
    let wrapAlgo = {
        name:"AES-GCM",
        length:256
    };
    let aesGcmParams = {
        name:"AES-GCM",
        iv: window.crypto.getRandomValues(new Uint8Array(12))
    };
    let format = "jwk";
    let extractable=true;
    let keyUsages = ["encrypt", "decrypt"];

    let kek = await crypto.subtle.generateKey(
        wrapAlgo, 
        false, 
        ["wrapKey", "unwrapKey"]
    );

    let key = await window.crypto.subtle.generateKey(
        encAlgo,
        extractable, // the key is extractable (i.e. can be used in exportKey)
        keyUsages
    );
    console.log("key (CryptoKey)", key);
    console.log("key (jwk)", await crypto.subtle.exportKey("jwk", key));

    let wrappedKey = await crypto.subtle.wrapKey(
        format,
        key,
        kek,
        aesGcmParams
    );
    console.log("wrappedKey (ArrayBuffer)", wrappedKey);

    let unwrappedKey = await crypto.subtle.unwrapKey(
        format,
        wrappedKey,
        kek,
        aesGcmParams,
        encAlgo,
        extractable,
        keyUsages
    );
    console.log("unwrappedKey (jwk) ", await crypto.subtle.exportKey("jwk", unwrappedKey));

})();
```